# Is it possible to access regular FTP folder with Renci.SshNet library for SFTP?

Tags: c#, ftp, sftp

I have this code to access SFTP:

```
    private void InitializeSftpConnection()
    {
        FtpHost = _config.GetRequiredValue("FtpHost");
        FtpFolder = _config.GetRequiredValue("FtpFolder");
        FtpUsername = _config.GetRequiredValue("FtpUsername");
        FtpPassword = _config.GetRequiredValue("FtpPassword");

        using (var client = new SftpClient(FtpHost, 22, FtpUsername, FtpPassword))
        {
            client.Connect();
            var files = client.ListDirectory(".").Where(f => f.IsDirectory && f.Name == FtpFolder).Select(f => f.Name);
            if (!files.Any())
            {
                throw new Exception($"Remote FTP folder {FtpFolder} does'nt exist.");
            }
        }
    }
```

**It connects just fine to SFTP, but failing to connect to FTP.**

But it is failing on `client.Connect();` when I am trying to access regular FTP instead of SFTP. I tried changing port to 21, but it didn't help.

**Please advice! Thanks**

Comment: No, that library is for SSH and SFTP, not FTP.

Comment: Is there a library that can handle both? Preferable the simplest one, to write less code?